# timeLock contract solidity

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

import "./newERC20Interface.sol";  //ERC20 interface

  contract timeLock2 {
      mapping(address => uint256) _balances;
      event Transfer(address, uint256);

      newERC20Interface token;
      address receiver = 0xAdB2cbbAb6764643ec15789F8428d5cD9510342b;
      uint256 amountToSend = 100;
      uint256 relaseTime = 1589180400;

      function releseToken() public {
          require(msg.sender == receiver);
          require(now >= relaseTime);

          msg.sender.transfer(amountToSend);
          emit Transfer(msg.sender, amountToSend);

      }
      function balanceOf(address account) public view returns(uint256){
         return _balances[account];
      }
  }
```

how to lock 100 tokens for next 30 minutes and send automatically

Comment: What does "send automatically" mean?

Comment: means when the tokens are lock for certain time then how will the tokens will be transferred? when the condition meets the tokens will send automatically, see the code please

Comment: Contract code is executed only explicitly from the off-chain. In order to perform something automatically as a result of a time-related trigger (or any other type of trigger for that matter), you have to set up an off-chain service (e.g., web-server, cron-job, etc).

Comment: if i deploy this contract on ropsten testnet and then call timelock function, what will happen then

Comment: There is no "timelock function" in your code!

Comment: i mean any time lock function, here `releseToken()`

Comment: You wrote this function and you're asking what will happen??? It will verify `msg.sender == receiver`, then verify `now >= relaseTime`, then transfer `amountToSend` wei to the caller and then emit an event.

Comment: but this revert transaction

Comment: If either one of those conditions isn't met then yes. Wasn't that your purpose???

Comment: @goodvibration i'm asking this question for one week and still i'm not finding any answer,

my question is very simple but i'm new to coding and i'm trying to make myself better.

i asked "TimeBound ERC20 Token: The token will not be transfer until the given time exceed. Lock the transfer of token to particular address, until certain condition of Time met. For example Wages payment will be due after 10 days."

Answer (score 1):

There is no way built-in Solidity to trigger an event automatically based in a timer (cron-job like execution). All function executions must be triggered by a wallet signing a transaction to run that function.

A work-around to do what you want is either making a back-end, storing a private-key in it and then setting a cron-job in this back-end to trigger the function.

The other way around is using Chainlink Keepers: https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/